# Oracle TNS alias connection works, ezconnect does not

Tags: oracle, connection, sqlplus

Using sqlplus and a tns names alias, I can connect successfully:

```
sqlplus xxxxxx/yyyyyy@zzzzz

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Apr 17 15:48:14 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Sun Apr 17 2022 15:33:24 -04:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
```

I then took the tnsnames.ora entry:

```
tnsping zzzzz

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 17-APR-2022 15:58:46

Copyright (c) 1997, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\app\client\product\19.0.0\client_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host.domain.tld)(PORT = 1515)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = service.domain.tld)))
OK (50 msec)
```

and tried to connect using ezconnect syntax:

```
sqlplus xxxxx/yyyyyy@host.domain.tld:1515/service.domain.tld

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Apr 17 16:01:13 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Which failed as you can see.  I guess I'm missing something, but what?

Comment: Try giving in quotes after @ - sqlplus u/p@"ez string"

Comment: Please, show `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH` from your sqlnet.ora. Its default value is `(tnsnames, ldap, ezconnect)`, so if you changed it, you need to add `ezconnect` to enable it

Comment: boom!  That did it.  if you put this as an Answer I'll mark it correct